# I am unable to load @bazel_tool

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to get some broken, platform dependent C# code to compile using bazel and I'm having quite a lot of problems defining a platform.

I've defined two platforms:

```
platform (
   name = "darwin",
   constraint_values = [
     "@bazel_tools//platform:osx",
   ],
)
platform (
   name = "windows",
   constraint_values = [
     "@bazel_tools//platform:windows",
   ],
)
```

Which I then use in a select in a `genrule` somewhere else in the `BUILD` file:

```
cmd = select ({
   ":darwin" : "a bash command",
   ":windows" : "a long and complex windows command because windows is stupid and makes everything much much more complex than it has to be"
})
```

When I try to build something, however, I get an error along the lines of

```
no such package '@bazel_tools//platform': BUILD file not found on package path and referenced by //<package>:darwin
```

I take this to mean that `@bazel_tools` isn't available.

The [documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/platforms.html) claims that `@bazel_tools` is builtin, so this is quite a surprise to me -- to me "builtin", means "you don't have to do anything for this to be available to you". I haven't been able to find anything that will tell how to fix the problem either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the directory is platforms":

`@bazel_tools//platforms:osx"`

Comment: So it seems :-)

Answer (score 2):

`platform` rule doesn't define config setting you can use in select(). You should use `config_setting`

This worked for me:

```
config_setting(
  name = "darwin",
  constraint_values = [
     "@bazel_tools//platforms:osx",
     "@bazel_tools//platforms:x86_64"
  ]
)
config_setting(
  name = "linux_x86",
  constraint_values = [
     "@bazel_tools//platforms:linux",
     "@bazel_tools//platforms:x86_64"
  ]
)
```